# Are Spark SQL and Spark Dataset (Dataframe) API equivalent?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have tried Spark as Dataset (=Dataframe) API in Scala and Spark SQL.
I found that they are very similar.
For example,

```
df.filter($"c" > 10)
  .select("a", "b")
```

do the same work in Spark SQL

```
SELECT a, b
FROM df
WHERE c > 10
```

1. Every Spark SQL can be converted as Spark Dataset API and vice versa?
2. There is no difference in performance since both are optimized by Catalyst and Tungsten?
3. Is there any method to compare the performance of Dataset and SQL query? SparkUI is enough? Or is there any benchmarks?

**UPDATE:**

4. Is there any official answers about above questions? I mean, can I find the answers from http://spark.apache.org/ ?

I have found the performance test on Spark 1.6 at https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html

Is there any test or benchmarks on Spark 2.x?